# bash: change the hostname displayed without running the `exec bash` command

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, hostname

I have:

```
lohacker@john:~$
```

I have a function:

```
test1 () {
    sudo hostname philip
    echo something
}
```

If I try:

```
lohacker@john:~$ test1
something
lohacker@john:~$ hostname
philip
lohacker@john:~$
```

As you can see the hostname displayed does not change (it always remains john).

I have another function:

```
test2 () {
    sudo hostname philip
    exec bash
    echo something
}
```

If I try:

```
lohacker@john:~$ test2
lohacker@philip:~$
```

As you can see the hostname has changed but did not continue to execute the function until the end (it did not print `something` on the screen).

Is there a way to change the hostname displayed without running the `exec bash` command?

```
lohacker@john:~$ echo "$PS1"
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

There is a space after the dollar sign at the end of the line.

The `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc` command doesn't refresh the hostname displayed in the shell.

Comment: Does `source ~/.bashrc` help?

Comment: Hello. I see this has been posted to another SE site as well. Please limit to one SE site at a time thanks.

Comment: @pLumo No......

Comment: Crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/698206/13792

Comment: And the answer was found as a duplicate on the unix&linux site.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved it!

```
export PS1="${PS1//\\h/\$(hostname -s)}"
```